# Vertical scrollbar visible but not working

Tags: html, css

I have vertical scrollbar visible but not working. I didn't find the problem in my CSS code or I have a JavaScript witch block it.

**This is my CSS and HTML code:**

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background: #ececec;
}
body {
  font: 400 14px / 1.42857143 "Roboto", sans-serif;
  padding-top: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  min-width:300px;
  min-height:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="page-wrapper"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't have any content in your code.. when you will add a lot of content which will not fit in view then scrollbar will start working automatically...

Comment: i have many content i juste didn't copy all the code

Comment: there is scroll bar present in your code.. and its working so how you want it to be?

Comment: I am a beginner in javascript I use this file [http://altair_app.tzdthemes.com/assets/js/common.js]  with my html page I think this file  block the scrollbar witch is visible on my page but I can not get down
have you any idea?

Comment: its hard to find problem with just one js file.. it will be much easier if you could provide some jsFiddle...

Comment: @MuhammadUSman this is a jsFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/uoz9ubtn/]  
 this scrollbar should work because i use scroll on with wow.js and animate.css [http://www.megaptery.com/2014/08/wow-js-animation-scroll.html]  
thanks for your time

Comment: please move your 2 css properties overflow-x and overflow-y from html to body styles and scroll will appear.. here is Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uoz9ubtn/1/

Comment: i tried this solution but there is two vertical scrollbar  and when i scroll on the new bar the animation  is not working

Comment: how can i see the animation in working?

Comment: i update  the jsFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/uoz9ubtn/3/] where animation not working

Comment: in jsFiddle animation is not working bcz of errors in console..

Answer (score 1):

`html {overflow-y: scroll;}` will always show scrollbar placeholder. Remove that or change to `auto`

Comment: when i change html {overflow-y: auto;} the scrollbar will be not visible

Comment: @lolla If there is no content to show scrollbar, than it will be hidden.